# dispatcherServlet bean collision issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run some spring boot application, but i am getting below issue:

```
    :: Built with Spring Boot :: 2.3.1.RELEASE                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2020-08-30 17:43:17.953 GMT+05:30  INFO rid=NA cid=NA 21756 --- [           main] o.s.s.petclinic.PetClinicApplication     : Starting PetClinicApplication v2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on saasas-WX-3 with PID 21756 (C:
\work\upstream\fault-tolerance-demo\target\spring-petclinic-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar started by krsoni in C:\work\upstream\fault-tolerance-demo)                                                                  
2020-08-30 17:43:17.959 GMT+05:30  INFO rid=NA cid=NA 21756 --- [           main] o.s.s.petclinic.PetClinicApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default                     
2020-08-30 17:43:19.799 GMT+05:30  WARN rid=NA cid=NA 21756 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org
.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dispatcherServlet' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/asr/autoconfigure/asr/ASRAutoConfiguration
.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=com.mycompany.asr.
autoconfigure.asr.ASRAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=getDispatcherServlet; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/asr/autoconfigure/asr/ASRAutoConfigur
ation.class]] for bean 'dispatcherServlet': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBea
nName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dispatcherServlet; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred)
; defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.class]] bound.                                             
2020-08-30 17:43:19.811 GMT+05:30  INFO rid=NA cid=NA 21756 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.                                                                                                 
2020-08-30 17:43:19.813 GMT+05:30 ERROR rid=NA cid=NA 21756 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
***************************                                                                                                                                                                                       
APPLICATION FAILED TO START                                                                                                                                                                                       
***************************                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Description:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
The bean 'dispatcherServlet', defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/asr/autoconfigure/asr/ASRAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path r
esource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Action:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Class where this bean definition is below. And its a third party jar ,which cant be modified:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("asr.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AsrProperties.class)
public class ASRAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    AsrProperties asrProperties;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer getEmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        // this property is accessed from many Contexts, so setting in system is the easiest
        System.setProperty("org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE", "true");

        // configure Tomcat based on properties
        AsrTomcatProperties asrTomcatProperties = new AsrTomcatProperties();
        asrTomcatProperties.setConnectionTimeout(asrProperties.getServer().getConnectionTimeout());
        asrTomcatProperties.setMaxSwallowSize(asrProperties.getServer().getMaxSwallowSize());

        return new AsrEmbeddedTomcatCustomizer(asrTomcatProperties);
    }

    /**
     * This is done to disable Spring MVC dispatcherServlet
     */
    @Bean(name = "dispatcherServlet")
    public String getDispatcherServlet() {
        return "";
    }

    @Bean
    public WebApplicationExceptionResponseBuilder getWebApplicationExceptionResponseBuilder() {
        return new WebApplicationExceptionResponseBuilder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ScmContext getScmContext() {
        return new ScmContext();
    }
}
```

I followed these threads https://brudenko.com/spring-bean-override, https://blog.tratif.com/2018/03/08/when-two-beans-collide/ . But if i am setting **spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true**                                                                      in application.properties. I start getting below error:

```
   2020-08-30 18:24:14.438 GMT+05:30  INFO rid=NA cid=NA 13076 --- [           main] o.s.s.petclinic.PetClinicApplication     : Starting PetClinicApplication v2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on sasas-WX-3 with PID 13076 (C:
\work\upstream\fault-tolerance-demo\target\spring-petclinic-2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar started by krsoni in C:\work\upstream\fault-tolerance-demo)                                                                  
2020-08-30 18:24:14.444 GMT+05:30  INFO rid=NA cid=NA 13076 --- [           main] o.s.s.petclinic.PetClinicApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default                     
2020-08-30 18:24:16.293 GMT+05:30 ERROR rid=NA cid=NA 13076 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on de.codecentric.spring.boot.chaos.monkey.configuration.ChaosMonkeyConfiguration.chaosMonkeyRestEndpoint                                             
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)                                                                                              
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)                                                                                                      
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)                                        
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)                                
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)                                                     
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)                                                          
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)                                                     
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)                                           
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)                                                       
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)                                                                    
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)                                                                                            
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)                                                                   
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)                                                                                                                         
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)                                                                                                                         
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)                                                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)                                                                                                                             
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)                                                                                                                            
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)                                                                                                                            
        at org.springframework.samples.petclinic.PetClinicApplication.main(PetClinicApplication.java:32)                                                                                                          
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                                                                                            
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                          
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)                                                                                                                                  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.mycompany.asr.autoconfigure.asr.ASRAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5197848c]  
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)                                                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)                                                                                                                       
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)                                                                                                            
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:743)                                             
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742)                                                      
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681)                                                          
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)                                                              
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1608)                                                                                             
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)                                                                                                      
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                                        
        ... 46 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2020-08-30 18:24:16.299 GMT+05:30  WARN rid=NA cid=NA 13076 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.mycompany.asr.autoconfigure.asr.ASRAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5197848c]             
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                      
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer                                                                                           
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)                                                                                                                                                     
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                              
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                                     
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)                                                                                                                  
        ... 29 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                              
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer                                                                                         
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                                      
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                                        
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)                                                                                                      
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                                        
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web` autoconfigures a bean with name `dispatcherServlet` of type `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`, so you cannot redefine it as a bean of type `String`, unless you allow it. --- When you allow it, your bean of type `String` replaces the bean of type `DispatcherServlet`. Why would you want to define a bean of that *very special* name with that type? It makes no sense. Web autoconfiguration looks for a bean named `dispatcherServlet` and tries to coerce the found bean to type `DispatcherServlet`, but you cannot create a `DispatcherServlet` from a `String`.

Comment: @Andreas : String type bean is defined in some third party jar. I didnt define it. Now how to solve this problem, as i cant make changes in thirdparty jar

Comment: A thirdparty jar that creates a bean of type `String` named `dispatcherServlet` cannot be used with `spring-boot-starter-web`. It's probably supposed to be used with Spring, not Spring Boot. --- Try to exclude the `@Configuration` component that has the `@Bean` method from the component scan, so it doesn't mess up your container.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-the-spring-mvc-dispatcherservlet

'If you have additional servlets you can declare a @Bean of type Servlet or ServletRegistrationBean for each and Spring Boot will register them transparently to the container. Because servlets are registered that way, they can be mapped to a sub-context of the DispatcherServlet without invoking it.

Configuring the DispatcherServlet yourself is unusual but if you really need to do it, a @Bean of type DispatcherServletPath must be provided as well to provide the path of your custom DispatcherServlet.'